# How to make a low pass filter for a differential equation for PID control?

Tags: python, numpy, derivative, pid-controller

So I'm trying to model a correct PID system in python but if I add some noise to the signal (by say a sensor) the D term starts overreacting. I know this is quite common and people fix it using a low pass filter yet I have no idea how to implement one.

So first I have a simple logistic growth function for the temperature:

```
time = np.arrange(0., maxtime, dt)
for t in time:
    temperature = temperature + temperature*50*dt*(1-temperature/150)
```

Now I import random and I add some noise to the signal (let's say this is caused by an imperfect real life sensor):

```
    temperature = temperature + random.randint(-1,1)/10
```

I won't have the complete code for the PID but say our system can only cool down the temperature, not heat it up, then I have something like this:

```
    if (P+I+D < 0):
        temperature = temperature + dt*(P+I+D)
```

The problem is that the system reacts a lot to the extra noise generated, I need a way to fix this. The way I have my D term coded is something like this (where Kd is a constant for the derivative:

```
    D = ((previousTemperature - temperature) / dt)*Kd
```

Note that I don't use error in the D term because otherwise it reacts extremely to a sudden change in the desired value of temperature, by this our derivative constant might need to be negative to not counteract the system.

My question is if there's a way to stop the derivative from overreacting to the noise.

Comment: You could pre-process your temperature signal to reduce the amount of noise, for example by using an exponential moving average. This will make your system slower to react, but filter out some noise.